# PHP json array to delete a line in JSON file

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, json

Having a bit of an issue with some PHP code.  I have an contacts list angular app to add and remove contacts.  I have the add part done but the delete is giving me some grief. On ng-click I'm sending data with a $http request to remove a specific line in a JSON file.  It's sending the data fine but I think something is wrong with my php...

delete.php

```
    $jsonString = file_get_contents("contacts.json");
$contactData = json_decode($jsonString, true);

$getArray = array(
    "firstname" => $_POST['firstname'],
    "lastname"  => $_POST['lastname'],
    "number"    => $_POST['number'],
    "hobbies"   => $_POST['hobbies']
);

foreach ($contactData as $key => $value) {
    if($value->number == $getArray) {
        unset($contactData[$key]);
    }
}

$json = json_encode($contactData, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
//Add to JSON contents
file_put_contents("contacts.json", $json);
```

app.js

```
$scope.deleteRow = function(contact){
    console.log(contact);
    //var index = $scope.number.indexOf(item);
    $http({
        method   : 'POST',
        url      : 'delete.php',
        data     : $.param(contact),
        headers  : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    })
    .success(function(data){
        updateService.listWasUpdated();
    });
};
```

html

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Bold" ng-click="deleteRow(contact)">
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) is being called with `assc==true` the returning array is associative, and you should use `$value['number']` instead of `$value->number`

Here is a corrected version with the [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function for brevity:

```
//load
$jsonString = file_get_contents("contacts.json");
$contactData = json_decode($jsonString, true);
//filter
$contactData = array_filter($contactData, function ($v) {return $v['number']!=$_POST['number'];});
//save
$json = json_encode($contactData, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
file_put_contents("contacts.json", $json);
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are not specifying the number key under the $getArray in the If statement, it needs to be replace with `$getArray['number']`.

```
if($value->number == $getArray['number']) {
    unset($contactData[$key]);
}
```

Is there a reason you are not using [SQLite](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite.php) to store your contact info? 
It would make it a lot easier to handle storing and manipulating of your contacts.

Comment: voting up for the suggestion to use a SQLite

Comment: Yeah I know a database is the correct way to go, but this is just a learning app for angular and only working with like 10 lines of JSON.